# Getting 15th digit

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

variable contains 15 digits,how to get 15th digit value from another function?

```
Function isvalid(stringvalue As String) As Boolean
Dim methodToCall As String
methodToCall = "somefunction"
isvalid = stringvalue Like "[0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]####[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][methodToCall(stringvalue)]"
```

Here the methodToCall will call another function and that function is return value for my **15th** digit
How to get the Value from anothor function from **isvalid** function

Comment: Please edit your question to show sample inputs and outputs.  Seems like you pattern only have 14 characters though?

Comment: 01AAACA0123A1Z(last digit from my function it is Alpha numeric)

Comment: At least in vb6 (don't know about vba): `mid$(stringvariable, 15, 1)` will return the 15th character of that string variable.

Comment: Again - that only has 14 characters.  Please also note that "digit" and "character" are not the same thing: "digit" typically only means 0-9

Comment: yeah i agree but the above example is clear for you.i can't express correctly sorry

Answer (score 2):

Say we have a string containing with a mixture of digits and other characters and we want the 15<sup>th</sup> digit.  The UDF:

```
Public Function GetFifteenth(sin As String) As Variant
    kount = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(sin)
        ch = Mid(sin, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(ch) Then
            kount = kount + 1
            If kount = 15 Then
                GetFifteenth = CLng(ch)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    GetFifteenth = ""
End Function
```

should do that.  For example:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim s As String, L As Variant
    s = "t2}nf[aW(494U,Oay8OWkh{xa*9>9b2SY5yPt14;m98AYd$|>U%orIJ[iF*Q)0w21!0:eX9,kU<_ x=B+cAFU<)%@{JMSze}"
    L = GetFifteenth(s)
    MsgBox L
End Sub
```

[image]

The code would be a little simpler if the string always contained exactly 15 digits.

Comment: i want to get the value from excel sheet using formula. here i cant use formula

Comment: What do you mean? [@Gary's Student](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student) coded for you a PUBLIC FUNCTION. If you put that into your Excel file, you can call it from a normal cell because it's an  UDF (User Defined Function). Of course you can use formula!

Comment: isvalid = stringvalue Like "[0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]####[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][methodToCall(stringvalue)]".            I mean Here "isvalid"is fetch the value from my cell and send the 14 characters or digits to the function I mention above named "somefunction" .that function will give 15nthdigit or character to the "isvalid" function